# Sample Space of such a random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Suppose there is a random experiment in which a person is asked to flip a coin $3$ times. The coin has $2$ sides (numbers and pictures). In the sample space of the random experiment, $3$ random variables are defined, namely:

• $A_1=$ The number of numbers that appear on the first $2$ toss

• $A_2=$ The Number of Numbers that appeared on the last $2$ roll

• $A_3=$ The number of numbers that appear in all throws

(a) Determine the sample space of the random experiment and the value space of the random variable $(A_1,A_2,A_3)$.

(a) The sample space of the random experiment and the value space of the random variable $(A_1,A_2,A_3)$

(b) Joint Density Probability of the random variable $(A_1,A_2,A_3)$

(c) Marginal Joint Density Probability of Random Variable $(A_1,A_2,A_3)$

(d) Conditional Probability Density of $A_3$ given $A_1=_1$ and $A_2=_2$

**My Work** (Anyone can help? Thank you)

(a) Sample space and value space:
The sample space is the set of all possible outcomes of the experiment. In this case, each coin flip can result in either a number or a picture, so there are $2^3 = 8$ possible outcomes. The sample space is given by:

$$S = \{(N, N, N), (N, N, P), (N, P, N), (N, P, P), (P, N, N), (P, N, P), (P, P, N), (P, P, P)\}$$

The value space of the random variable $(A_1, A_2, A_3)$ is determined by the possible values that each $A_i$ can take. Since each $A_i$ represents the number of numbers in a sequence of coin flips, the possible values are $0, 1, 2$, and $3$. Therefore, the value space is:

$$(A_1, A_2, A_3) \in \{(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), \ldots, (3, 3, 3)\}$$

Comment: The outcome $(3, 3, 3)$ is impossible.

Comment: In (b) and (c) and (d) it is a probability *mass* function not a *density*.  If each possible outcome has probability $\frac18$ in (b) you should have $8$ possibilities in (a).  What does "marginal joint" mean? If it just means "marginal", you may be expected to calculate $P(A_1=0), P(A_1=1), P(A_1=2),  P(A_3=0)$ etc.

Comment: @Henry I'm confused, how do I do it? Sorry for points (b), (c), and (d), there have been changes, so I misunderstood it.